# How to setup .htaccess rewrite url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, apache2

how do I setup a redirect as follows:

Redirect these:

```
http://www.domain.com.au/browse-stores/storeA
http://www.domain.com.au/browse-stores/storeB
```

To these

```
http://www.domain.com.au/browse-stores?centre=storeA
http://www.domain.com.au/browse-stores?centre=storeB
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^browse-stores/(.+)$ /browser-stores?centre=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you actually wanted to redirect the browser so that the URL in the address bar changes, change the flags in the brackets to `[L,QSA,R=301]`.

Comment: Hi, thank you seems to redirect even if I don't have R=301 :( Maybe it's my config?

Comment: @Brettski is it redirecting when you are missing a trailing slash (like: `http://www.domain.com.au/browse-stores/storeA`) to a URL with a trailing slash?